# Uri from FilePath

Tags: android

I am using the *Gallery3D*-Code but want it to only display images from a sub-folder on the SD, not all of the images that are stored on it. To do this, I tried to change

`public static final Uri STORAGE_URI = Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;`

to

`public static final Uri STORAGE_URI = Uri.fromFile(new File(ROOT_DIR));`,

where
`String ROOT_DIR =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/mySubDirectory";`

but I guess  this is transforming a `content://`-Uri to a `file://`-Uri and this may be a problem?

In any case, it doesn't work :-(! Instead of just showing images from the `ROOT_DIR`-directory and its sub-directories, it shows no images at all ("Gallery empty"). Could anyone point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also (later) asked this question on the Android Developer Google Group and the consensus there was that with the current structure of the Gallery3D code, my goal isn't possible and I would have to change the images-source to a (custom) database in which my image-paths are stored.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

I'm assuming you mean the [Open Source code for Gallery3D](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Gallery3D.git;a=blob;f=src/com/cooliris/media/ImageManager.java).  Instead of changing the content provider Uri in `STORAGE_URI`, have you looked at changing `CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME` in `ImageManager.java` and/or `CAMERA_BUCKET_NAME` in `LocalDataSource.java`?

I see [several places](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Gallery3D.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=getExternalStorageDirectory) where `getExternalStorageDirectory()` is mentioned.

**Old Answer**

Try using [`withAppendedPath(Uri baseUri, String pathSegment)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#withAppendedPath%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29) to add your subdirectory to the Uri.  Perhaps something like this would work for you:

```
Uri.withAppendedPath(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
    Uri.encode("mySubDirectory"));
```

Comment: Thanks, Brian. Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. I have only seen `withAppendedPath` being used with a String as the path, e.g. `Uri u2 = Uri.withAppendedPath(u, "1");` which makes u2: `content://media/external/images/media/1`, I don't think an actual Uri-encoded path is a valid extension of the base-Uri? I guess I need to filter the `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA`-Column by filepath...somehow?

Comment: I had suggested using `Uri.encode()` since the documentation for `pathSegment` said it took an "encoded path segment to append".  I've edited my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I already tried changing the camera-bucket to my directory (rather than leaving it at `/DCIM`), but that piece of code just seems to handle the camera-label and -icon on the respective camera-folder (i.e. whether to show a "Camera"-icon or a normal "Folder"-icon).